# Fetching full user emails via google code api

Tags: python, google-code

I'm using this(http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/IssueTrackerAPIPython) python library to fetch data from google code project. When I get list of issues, some issue reporter's emails are hidden (f.e. "exam...@gmail.com" instead of "example@gmail.com"). 
How can I get full email for such users?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to get the full email.  It's hidden to reduce the amount of spam.

**Edit:**
From the url you linked, I found a link to the full API reference, http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/IssueTrackerAPIReference, if you were to be able to get the user's email, it would be in here.